# Why does memory get corrupted?

Tags: c, memory

I have the folowing 2 functions:

```
void compute_key(uint8_t * stream, int key_length, int stream_length, uint8_t * key) {

    // there will be key_length encrypted streams;
    uint8_t ** encr_streams;
    int * bytes_in_stream;
    encr_streams = (uint8_t **)malloc(key_length * sizeof **encr_streams);
    bytes_in_stream = (int *)malloc(key_length * sizeof *bytes_in_stream);
    for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++) bytes_in_stream[i] = 0;

    construct_cypherstreams(stream, key_length, stream_length, encr_streams, bytes_in_stream);

    printf("%s\n", "bytes_in_stream[]");
    for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", bytes_in_stream[i]);
    }

    getchar();

    for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++) bytes_in_stream[i] = 7; // introduced in step #2
    printf("\n%s\n\n", "cypherstreams:");
    for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes_in_stream[i]; j++) {
            printf("%X", encr_streams[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }


    // for each cypherstream, compute ByteB - the value they were XOR`d with
    compute_key_using_scoring(encr_streams, bytes_in_stream, key_length, key);

    getchar();
}
void construct_cypherstreams(uint8_t * stream, int key_length, int stream_length, uint8_t ** encr_streams, int * bytes_in_stream) {
    // chyperstream = the stream formed of every ith byte
    uint8_t * cypherstream;
    int length;
    length = stream_length / key_length + 1;
    // each byte of the key can have values
    // between 0 and 256
    int i = 0;
    int num_added = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < key_length; k++) {
        i = k; num_added = 0;
        cypherstream = (uint8_t *)malloc(length * sizeof *cypherstream);
        if (cypherstream == NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", "could not allocate");
            exit(1);
        }
        while (i < stream_length) {
            // construct cypherstream
            cypherstream[num_added] = stream[i];
            num_added++;
            i += key_length;
        }
        // this is always correct
        printf("\n%s\n", "created cypherstream:");
        for (int m = 0; m < num_added; m++) {
            printf("%X", cypherstream[m]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        encr_streams[k] = cypherstream;
        bytes_in_stream[k] = num_added;
        // this is always correct
        printf("%s%d%s %d\n", "bytes_in_stream[", k, "]", bytes_in_stream[k]);
    }
}
```

My `key_length` is `31` and I know for sure it`s good (computed before, also for other values, for which the program get to the end and prints a decrypted chypertexht).

In `construct_cypherstreams` I am passing pointers to dinamically allocated memory in `compute_key`.
My intention is to populate a 2D array, `encr_streams` and a 1D array `bytes_in_stream`, of unknown sizes at compile-time.

In `construct_cypherstreams`, I print the contents of `bytes_in_stream[k]` after each iteration and I get valid data. There are 7 bytes in each stream, everything works as expected. I also print the newly formed `encr_streams[k]` and I also get expected values.

At step #1, after the program returns from `construct_cypherstreams`, i check to see if the contents of `bytes_in_stream` are correct, and I see the first 7 values are garbage and I really don`t understand why. I have written a lot of dummy examples to populate an array of all kinds inside a function and they all seem to work.

At step #2, when I got really frustrated, I just populated `bytes_in_stream` with the values I knew it should contain, so that I can get to the next part of the code. To my surprise, when I am trying to print `encr_streams`, my program crashes when `i` gets to be `24` (there are a total of 31 `encr_streams`).

I really don`t understand why this happens and I get the feeling that I am on a case of undefined behaviour.

The program is running smooth when it finds `key_length` to be `6`, for another stream.

Comment: `Why does memory get corrupted?` - have you tried running valgrind?

Comment: I am on Windows, I run in VS2013 and I don't see anything wrong. That`s why I want to see if there is a logical bug in my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
encr_streams = (uint8_t **)malloc(key_length * sizeof **encr_streams);
```

It should be:

```
encr_streams = (uint8_t **)malloc(key_length * sizeof *encr_streams);
```

Comment: because I want to allocate size for the pointers, but I was allocating size for `char`s. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Now this might sound silly, but can you please tell me how you found it?

Comment: I first looked at `bytes_in_stream` since that was getting corrupted.  When I looked at how it was allocated, I noticed the line next to it.  You can see one has ** and the other has *.  Normally when you malloc, you do `sizeof *variable` with one * only.